# Best matchmaking algorithm for 5v5s within player pools of millions of players

Tags: algorithm, matchmaking

Suppose that I am trying to create some sort of match making algorithm for my game. The game is similar to League or DOTA, whereby 5 players are pitted against 5 players. Suppose further that the player pool is gigantic (millions of players searching for a game at a time), and the job of the match maker is to put as many players as possible into many instances of 5v5 games. At this point, we do not worry at all about MMR, ELO or any player/party rating coming into play. We just want to place players into 5v5s.

My current brute-force algorithm is absolutely atrocious in scaling. It first tries to find all possible combinations of 5 player parties within the millions of players, then, it tries to find pairs of parties, while removing players from possible party matches if the players have already been used:

So, suppose I have 10 players and I want to find all possible 5v5s, I first transform them into bits and do bit shifting to find all possible combinations.

```
Players: ABCDEFGHIJ
1111100000 => ABCDE
1111010000 => ABCDF 
1111001000 => ABCDG
1111000100 => ABCDH
1111000010 => ABCDI
1111000001 => ABCDJ
1110110000 => ABCEF
```

and so on...

Then out of all possible parties, I use 2 for loops to start trying to find pairs of parties:

```
ABCDE vs FGHIJ
ABCDF vs EGHIJ
ABCDG VS EFHIJ
```

and so on...

This algorithm has run time of O((nCr)^2). Because it tries to find all possible party combinations, just matchmaking 50 players would require 4.4891439e+12 operations, which is insane.

What is a better algorithm that doesn't go through all possible parties and brute-force this problem?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the problem, but If you don't care about MMR or ELO or any sort of metric...then can't you just randomly choose from your player pool 5 players at a time and pair team 1 with team 2, and team 3 with team 4, etc..?

Comment: Your constraints are very unclear. A simple partitioning of players seems fine. I've never played Legend or DOTA, so this is not helpful to me either. You need to be more clear about what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I didn't make it clear but I meant I wanted all possible combinations of 5v5 matches. So for example, if there are 6 players, ABCDEF and we are creating 2v2s: Then, AB vs CD, BC vs DE, AC vs DE, AE vs DF are 4 of the possible combinations. In this case, it doesn't matter what the ratings are. I want a list of all possible 2v2s from 6 players

Comment: First you asked for something non brute-force, now you want to list all combinations (which is always brute-force). The question is approaching a closed state as it's really hard to get what you really want.

Comment: I dont understand it's not that complicated. I'm just asking if there are 4 players ABCD and we are looking for all possible 2v2s, what is the best algorithm to generate the combinations AB vs CD, AC vs BD, and AD vs BC? That's all I want, and it has absolutely nothing to do with skill ratings. If bruteforce is the only solution, then so be it cause I didn't know

Comment: I was just pointing out that the way I was doing it, it was O(nCr)^2 and there must have been a better way. I also explained in the case of ABCD, then you generate all possible pairs of 2, they are AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, and CD. Then, I come up with the 2v2 matches

Comment: There is no easy solution, read more here http://www.ifaamas.org/Proceedings/aamas2017/pdfs/p1073.pdf

Answer (score 3):

From your example, I gather that you don't care about gathering players by rating classes, but that you *do* care about balancing the resulting teams.  Here's an algorithm that should get you a workable solution.  Start by grabbing the first 9 players in the queue; call this the `pool`.

1. Compute the average rating of the players, `avg = mean(pool)`
2. Compute the target score for a team of 5: `team_target = 5*avg`
3. Find the combination of 5 players whose ratings have a sum closest to `team_target` (solved in several other postings).  Make that team1.
4. Compute total rating of the team: `team1_rating = sum(team1)`
5. Remove those five players from the `pool`.  Put the remaining pool players onto team2.
6. Compute the rating of this remaining team of 4: `team2_rating = sum(team2)`
7. Subtract the ratings to get the rating of the needed 10th player: `player_target` = team1_rating - team2_rating
8. Grab the next 10 players in the queue; this is the new `pool`.
9. Find the pool player with the rating closest to `player_target`.
10. Put that player onto `team2` and post the match **team1 vs team2*.
11. There are 9 players left in the pool; go back to step 1.  Iterate as necessary.

**ADVANTAGES**

This is a simple, linear algorithm that can handle a stream of input requests.  Since the team size is fixed, it's **O(N)** on the length of the queue.  The only part that's at all time-consuming is finding the team closest to the average rating, checking 9C5 = 126 possibilities, a pretty cheap overhead per match.

The space overhead is trivial: the high-water mark is handling 19 players at once.

**PROBLEMS**

You can have an unbalanced match if the distribution isn't smooth.  For instance, a queue with one star player, such as (100, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6 | 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6) will give you team ratings of 120 and 30 for the "best" pairing.  If this is a functional problem for you, feel free to adjust, perhaps keeping a pool of outliers to handle until you get 10 high and/or 10 low ones.